# Is there a Search parameter Modifier for querying a value against a fixed position('first' or 'last') of an array-like element in a Resource?

Tags: hl7-fhir

I want to filter `Encounter`s based on their first or last `Encounter.location[]`.
FHIR REST api spec has only 1 search param related to Encounter location value: `location` and it doesn't specify the search behaviour in case when Cardinality is greater than 1.

I was hoping for a modifier suffix like `:first` or `:last` to support `location:first`, `location:last` i.e
`{base_url}/Encounter?location:last=Location/123`

but there is no such option and I don't see a way to add custom parameter modifiers.

Is there a preferred way than adding custom search params like `location-last`, `location-first` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to be aware of is that order is only significant when the base FHIR specification declares it to be significant - which it doesn't for Encounter.location.  As a result, you should expect the locations to be listed in arbitrary order and the 'first' location won't mean anything special.  The period of time when a location is/was relevant is conveyed by Encounter.location.period, not ordering within the collection.  It's non-conformant to enforce any rules about ordering when FHIR hasn't defined any.

There are currently no qualifiers to support searching on a specific repetition.  However, it is possible to define custom search parameters that can be tied to a specific repetition.  E.g. If you wanted to only search on a patient's "first" name as opposed to all given names.  Be aware that defining custom search parameters is only useful if you're in an environment where you can nudge both clients and servers to support the custom parameter.

You could submit a change request (use the link at the bottom of any page in the spec) proposing the :first and :last modifiers for inclusion in R5 of FHIR, but you'd have to provide several examples of places where it would be useful (constrained to places where order is actually significant)

Comment: Thanks, @lloyd-mckenzie. Makes sense. Is there an instance in base FHIR spec where order is declared to be significant? Also, is it conformant to enforce/bake in order info for Encounter.location by using an extension to specify the position/index in the repetition?. About change request, someday, probably. We don't have many usecases for it yet.

Comment: Address.line, Bundle.entry, HumanName.given, prefix and suffix are the only places where order has been defined as meaningful somehow.  It's totally fine (and appropriate) to put extensions on things to convey order/preference/importance.  There are standard extensions for doing that for a few places, but not on Encounter.location.  However, given that Encounter.location has period, that probably satisfies most implementers requirements for an ordering.